Question on strange Payload Status using REST API
I am trying to get data from DE and then Push those data into Journey Event. Good thing is it's working and bad thing is I am getting the below error while testing the solution in CloudPage... In my test DE i have four records, I can see all four records injected into the Journey and also I can see them added onto Journey Event DE. But interestingly I am seeing the below error in CloudPage, any idea what could be the cause?
payload:
Failed to inject contact into the journey. Status: 201payload:
Failed to inject contact into the journey. Status: 201payload:
Failed to inject contact into the journey. Status: 201payload:
Failed to inject contact into the journey. Status: 201

Thanks.

It is always good practice to share the code you are using, otherwise we have hard time guessing what could potentially be wrong with your code.
Luckily, I have been able to use my mind reading skills to see that you are using SSJS to build this Cloud Page, and the code that seems to be giving you hard time is this part here:
if response.status_code == 202 {
print("Contact injected into the journey successfully.") 
} else { 
print("Failed to inject contact into the journey. Status:", response.status_code)
}

The issue is, that you are expecting 202 status code for successful execution. The correct code is 201. Please update the script and try again.
